# Xcode can't implement web view using AMSlidemenu

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have been using `AMSlidemenu` with multiple `AMSlideMenuContentSegue`s.

They all work fine at the moment as they just display a label.

The first view controller I have added a web view and given it its own custom class .h and .m file which point to a url but every time I launch the application crashes.

.....

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [websiteWebview loadRequest:requestURL];             **Thread 1: Breakpoint 1.1**


    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

......

I dont understand whats happening ... I m a novice when it comes to Xcode so any help will be appreciated.

I hope I have contextualized my problem.

Comment: First of all, thanks for using AMSlideMenu library :) 

Can you please provide a screenshot of your storyboard (where I can see MainVC, Menu, and Content View Controller with webView)?

Thanks

Comment: And please, add also a console log of crash

Comment: I have tried with webView, and it works. No crash...

Comment: Here are some screenshots ... and yes AMSlidemenu is awesome http://i62.tinypic.com/4ropc3.png  http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=732ty1&s=8   http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=zmkpqx&s=8    http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=jh6mir&s=8   http://i58.tinypic.com/30th2py.png

Comment: here is my console ... i don't think i get any errors http://oi62.tinypic.com/xkvbt4.jpg

Comment: @arturdev I have changed my view's class to MainVC and placed the web view code in it. I now get this error. http://oi57.tinypic.com/20hsztz.jpg ... would love it if you had a small working version you could upload or send me to see how you have implemented your web view.